# What is "Photo Chromography" and when would it have been in use?

Tags: terminology, technique, alt-process, colorization

I have an old photo of a woman that is in a very thick beveled glass and on the back it has print stating "Photo Chromography". It is an advertisement saying "This the most recent discovery in photographic Science which a life like reproduction can be made. Send any photograph or tin type in color. They are all made on this heavy plate glass and sold complete with a handsome wire easel for $1.50 each and your original photo will be returned. From the Novelty Photo Co."

First of all I don't find the word "Chromography" online — only "Chromatography". I would really like to know when this process was first used so I can get an idea how old this is. The picture of the woman is during the Civil War era but they could have used any era photo for advertising purposes.

Comment: I would have to do more digging to before adding a proper answer with dates, but in the meantime you could try adding "-chromatography" to your searches to filter out the 'helpful corrections' search engines are likely to attempt if you want to look more for yourself. [I got a number of good photography hits with it, but didn't quickly find clear dates.]

Comment: Could you provide a photo of the photo?

Answer (score 2):

The word is fairly generic, and seems like it could easily have been applied separately to a number of different things. For example, I found [this from 1969](https://books.google.com/books?id=28rDAAAAIAAJ&q=Chromography&dq=Chromography&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu5_XuqqLhAhVSrp4KHeSFCxMQ6AEwCHoECAEQAg) — "A new electronic method called Chromography re-creates paintings in such exact detail that experts find it difficult to tell the Chromograph from the original." — but I think [this booklet from 1871](https://books.google.com/books?id=fJcPus7WuzcC&dq=Chromography&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) is probably most relevant. That certainly fits your Civil War era identification. From the booklet:

> ## PHOTO-CHROMOGRAPHY
>
> By  this   simple process any   person unaccustomed to painting, and  ignorant of art,  may   colour photographs, and  produce, with rapidity and   little trouble, effective, permanent, and   beautiful pictures, so  soft   and   delicate as  to closely resemble painting on  enamel; may   render the  treasured family portrait doubly valuable by addingt he   warm tints of life   to  the  faithful but   cold and deathlike   production of  the  photographer, and produce a pleasing as  well as  a truthful representation. The largest and the   smallest work maybe  painted with equal facility — the life-size portrait, or a miniature for a locket — the only   qualification for  success, even   in very elaborate pictures, being taste in  the   arrangement of the colours.

The booklet consists of half a dozen pages of instructions, and then as many pages of advertisement for materials.

The process described is to apply a "Diaphanous Varnish" to the printed photograph so the paper becomes translucent, and then paint on the back side. It is not at all as automatic as the flowery description indicates. (For example, the instructions say "First apply the appropriate colour (pink) to  the  lips   and   cheeks very sparingly, softening the   latter with a dry   brush.")

I expect from the quote on your advertisement that some enterprising individual took this and decided to make a business of it. However, the process described in this booklet is destructive, and were it applied to the photo sent in, returning the original would have been impossible. Perhaps the entrepreneur first made a photographic reproduction, or perhaps they're using the same word to describe an entirely different process of coloring.